# How to create a paragraph in input?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyFile {
    private static File file = new File("text.txt");
    private static StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    
    public static void copyToClipboard(String text) {
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }
    
    private String readContent() {
        try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = fileReader.nextLine();
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    
    public void write(String content) {
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
            fileWriter.write(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
    public void read() {
        try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String content = fileReader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(content);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void delete() {
        while (true) {
            try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)) {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Are you sure you want to delete all the file content (y or n)?");
                String answer = scan.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                
                if (answer.equals("y")) {
                    fileWriter.write("");
                    System.out.println("Succesfully deleted all the file content.");
                    break;
                } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                    System.out.println("Cancelling...");
                    break;
                } else { 
                    System.out.println("An error has occured.");
                    continue;
                }
                    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error has occured.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
        }       
    }
    
    public void edit() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        MyFile file = new MyFile();
        String content = file.readContent();
        StringBuilder newContent = new StringBuilder();
        
        copyToClipboard(content);
        
        System.out.println("Enter new data or edit new (paste it). To stop editing, enter \"quitprogram\".");
        String line = "";
        
        do {
            line = scan.nextLine();

            if (line.equals("quitprogram")) {
                break;
            } else {
                newContent.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } while (!line.equals("quitprogram"));
        
        file.write(newContent.toString());
        
        System.out.printf("Successfully edited the text!\n\nNew text:\n%s", newContent);
    }
}
```

When I run particularly edit() method, it allows me to input some text and create a paragraph to input smt on another line. But if I open text.txt there won't be any paragraphs and all the text'd be written only on one line.

I try to make it possible to make paragraphs in input by using .append("\n"). However, it won't work even though user presses Enter and creates new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `System.lineSeparator` since the line separator is platform dependent. If you are in windows for instance you may not see the `\n` as a new line in some text editors.

That said, this is not ideal, since the text generated will be platform dependant. So, the reason why you may not be seeing the paragraphs could be that.

To test that, you could change:

```java
                newContent.append(line).append("\n");
```

by:

```java
                newContent.append(line).append(System.lineSperator());
```

Or just see the content with an hex editor to see if the `\n` is there, or choose a text editor that detects `\n` as a line separator on your platform.

I ran your code in my system shich is linux, and the paragraphs are there.

Answer (score 1):

I complied and ran your program on my computer. Your program successfully writes multi-line text into "text.txt" until user inputs "quitprogram" as expected.

The only issue is that the program doesn't open the file in append mode. This means that each time the write() method is called, a new FileWriter is created in overwrite mode. As a result, it starts writing from the beginning of the file rather than continuing from where it left off.

To fix this, you need to modify the program so that the FileWriter opens the file in append mode.

```
 public void write(String content) {
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true)) {
            fileWriter.write(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```